# DB backup is not being restored to another DB. It is showing "Specified cast is not valid" error

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have been experiencing "Specified cast is not valid" error while restoring backup of DB. Version of SQL server management tool from which I am taking the backup is "Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1) - 10.50.2500.0 (Intel X86)   Jun 17 2011 00:57:23   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition with Advanced Services on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (WOW64) (Hypervisor) ". And restoring to the same version tool.

I have tried all the suggested solutions that are mentioned on other posts but they do not work for me.

1. I have tried to do this by creating MDF and LDF files and attached them to my local DB.
2. I have also tried to generate script for this.
3. I have tried by updating SQL management tool to 2012 R2 but it doesn't work.

Is there any other solution to get this issue resolved?

Comment: try serverfault or http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

That seems to be a common error when restoring via SSMS. Assuming that is what you did, you can work around the issue by restoring via TSQL.

1. Grab the backup file details via "RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = N''"
2. Build your RESTORE command with proper MOVE option.

Final RESTORE command should look something like this:

```
RESTORE DATABASE [MyDb]
FROM DISK = N'C:\Backup\MyDb.bak'   
WITH MOVE N'MyDb_Data' TO N'D:\DATA\MyDb.mdf'
, MOVE N'MyDb_Log' TO N'E:\LOG\MyDb_log.ldf'
, REPLACE
```

Comment: Hi Greg, Thanks for your answer. But is also not working. It is showing error like 

"Msg 3203, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Read on "D:\DBRestore.bak" failed: 38(Reached the end of the file.)
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally."

I also want to make a tweak to your code. It is WITH MOVE not just MOVE.

Any other solution for this issue?

Comment: Thanks, i updated the code.  Please note that my answer above is the resolution for the original issue, you just so happen to now hit a new issue.   Basically, you have a corrupt backup file.  Please request a new backup file, and try again.